# Prove that $ a^{k} + b^{k} + c^{k} \ge a^{k-1}b + b^{k-1}c + c^{k-1}a$

Tags: inequality, polynomials, contest-math, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, rearrangement-inequality

> Prove  that  $ a^{k} + b^{k} + c^{k} \geq a^{k-1}b + b^{k-1}c + c^{k-1}a$  where $a, b, c$  are  positive  real  numbers  and  $k$  is a positive  integer.

I  don't  know  how  to  start.

Comment: Take a look at the rearrangement inequality.

Comment: I wish I knew about that one earlier. Goodness that's helpful

Answer (score 3):

Since $\left(a^{k-1},b^{k-1},c^{k-1}\right)$ and $(a,b,c)$ are the same ordered,

your inequality follows from Rearrangement:
$$a^k+b^k+c^k=a^{k-1}\cdot{a}+b^{k-1}\cdot{b}+c^{k-1}\cdot{c}\geq a^{k-1}b+b^{k-1}c+c^{k-1}a$$
Done!

Comment: The Re-Arrangement Inequality should be more widely known. It is very useful.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Use *Cauchy-Schwarz* inequality with the vectors $(a^{k-1}, b^{k-1}, c^{k-1})$ and $(u,v,w)$. When do we have equality?

B.t.w., the  *strict* inequality is false if $a=b=c$.

Answer (score 1):

A natural approach is the following.

Rewrite the inequality into
$$a^{k-1}(a-b) + b^{k-1}(b-c) + c^{k-1}(c-a) \ge 0.$$
Notice that $c-a = -(a-b) - (b-c)$, the last inequality can be rewritten as
$$a^{k-1}(a-b) + b^{k-1}(b-c) - c^{k-1}(a-b) - c^{k-1}(b-c) \ge 0.$$
Regrouping:
$$(a^{k-1} - c^{k-1})(a-b) + (b^{k-1}- c^{k-1})(b-c) \ge 0.$$
The first term is non-negative if we assume (WLOG) $a=\max(a,b,c)$, the second term is always non-negative, thus the inequality is clearly true.